# How can i get response status code from Goutte

Tags: php, web-crawler, goutte

I'm using [Goutte](https://github.com/FriendsOfPHP/Goutte) to parse some websites.

Here are my code example

```
$goutteClient = new Client();
$response = $goutteClient->setHeader('User-Agent', $userAgent)
->setClient($guzzleClient)
->request('GET', 'https://example.com');
```

`$response` is instance of `Symfony\Component\DomCrawler\Crawler`

So, how can I get response status code for checking it is 404 error or any other?

Answer (score 3):

`$goutteClient->getResponse()` will give you the Response object of the last request being done.

full code is:

```
$res = $goutteClient->getResponse();
if ($res->getStatusCode() === 404) {}
```

Answer (score 1):

It helped me

```
if ($goutteClient->getResponse()->getStatusCode() === 404){}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$status = $goutteClient->getResponse();
if($status == 404) {
[...]
}
```

Comment: this won't work, you need $status `=` and getResponse returns an object, if you test it with identical operator it will never match 404

Comment: Correct way is `$res = $goutteClient->getResponse();
                        if ($res->getStatusCode() === 404) {}`

Answer (score 0):

Worked for me on this way:

```
$response = $client->getInternalResponse();
if($response->getStatusCode() === 404){
   // NOT FOUND
}
```